# scikit-learn SGD Document Classifier : Using important features only

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a text files with documents and their description. I am using SGD Classifier available in scikit-learn to get two separate classes of documents. I have trained my model using the following code:

```
fo = open('training_data.txt','rb')
all_classes = np.array([0,1])

for i,line in enumerate(generate_in_chunks(fo,1000)):

    x = [member.split('^')[2] for member in line if member!="\n"]
    y = [member.split('^')[1] for member in line if member!="\n"]
    vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(decode_error='ignore', n_features=2 ** 18,non_negative=True)

    x_train =  vectorizer.transform(x)
    y_train = np.asarray(y,dtype=int)

    clf = SGDClassifier(loss='log',penalty='l2',shuffle=True)

    clf.partial_fit(x_train, y_train,classes=all_classes)
```

Now I am using this clf object on my test data set. Here I want to use transform mentioned in the tutorial:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

Code:

```
fo = open('test_data.txt','rb')
prob_comp = open('pred_prob_actual.txt','wb')
for i,line in enumerate(generate_in_chunks(fo,21000)):
    x = [member.split('^')[2] for member in line if member!="\n"]
    y = [member.split('^')[1] for member in line if member!="\n"]

    vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(decode_error='ignore', n_features=2 ** 18,non_negative=True)

    x_test =  vectorizer.transform(x)
    y_test = np.asarray(y,dtype=int)

    clf.predict(clf.transform(x_test))
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test.py", line 106, in 
    clf.predict(clf.transform(x_test))
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 223, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 204, in decision_function
    % (X.shape[1], n_features))

ValueError: X has 78 features per sample; expecting 206

So basically though it has identified important features but it is not able to use them while predicting on test data.

Any suggestion on how can i use transform method on test data would be widely appreciated.
**I want to use only the important features and looking out for ways which could help in doing that, just to make it more clear.**
Thanks.

Comment: For important features, I suggest you take a look at [TfIdfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer). With it, you'll be able to specify a `min_df` which can help you extract the more important features in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line to:

```
clf.predict(x_test.toarray())
```

You are transforming your dataset with `HashingVectorizer`, but this is not sufficient. You need to apply `toarray()` in order to get the matrix of feature vectors on which prediction is based.

Although, for readability and for "better" (in my opinion) code structuring I would recommend you adjust your code to:

```
x_train =  vectorizer.fit_transform(x)
...
x_test = vectorizer.transform(x).toarray()
y_test = np.asarray(y,dtype=int)

result = clf.predict(x_test)

print result
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I tried as you have suggested and getting the following error:                                                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 106, in <module>
    clf.predict(clf.transform(x_test).to_array())
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 499, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: to_array not found

Comment: @PappuJha Please have a look at my answer now. It should fix your problem.

Comment: @PappuJha How about now? Adjust the line for `x_train = fit_transform(x)`

Comment: Working Code:                                                                                     x_test = vectorizer.transform(x)                                                             y_test = np.asarray(y,dtype=int)                                                                 result = clf.predict(x_test)                                                                   print result  I believe this code is using all the features but I want to use only important feature. Does you updated answer addresses my concern. Thanks!!

Comment: @PappuJha But, you need it as an `array()` in order for the prediction to work correctly.

Comment: Sir I have a working code, that is not my problem. I want to utilize only important features produced by transform. Using tranform is a way, you may be answering some other way. Is that correct ? Please help to understand. Thanks